# Set Generic to a new instance in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I have a method that takes a Generic parameter. I've restricted the type to one of two. Within the method I want to set call one of the two constructors.

Code:

```
internal static void CreateAddress<T>(out T address, bool isSave, int? cID) where T: Address_Accessor, Address
 {
   DateTime dt= DateTime.Now;
   int? eID = 1;
   int? sID = 50;

   if (typeof(T) == typeof(Address_Accessor))
     address = new Address_Accessor(dt, eID , sID);
   else
     address = new Address(dt, eID, sID);
}
```

The compile failure says:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'Address_Accessor' to 'T'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: generics seem like a pretty terrible fit here. It seems like an overloaded method will do just fine.

Comment: Whats the relationship between Address_Accessor and Address?

Comment: This isn't proper, generics let you work with specific types, not just dynamically mix and match types.

Comment: Why would you have an `out` parameter in a method that doesn't otherwise return anything instead of just returning the address?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong here, but are you trying to define that `T` can inherit from more than a class? C# doesn't support multi-inheritance.

Comment: Note that once you get past the casting issue, the method would not compile because of your constraints. T can be constrained to at most *one* class, which restricts T to derive from that class. You cannot restrict T to one of two types, as your question states is your intent. But you arguably need a different approach entirely.

Comment: This is code that is part of a Test project. Address_Accessor is part of test class created by Unit Test framework to test protected Address properties.

Answer (score 1):

As a straightforward solution (not having any details regardign method usage cases) **if Address and Address_Accessor both represents some common entity** - just introduce a common interface and restrict `T` to implement this interface, then you would be able insatntiating any of class which implements `IAddress` and setting to the `IAddress` reference (behind T).

```
interface IAddress
{
}

class Address_Accessor : IAddress
class Address : IAddress

internal static void CreateAddress<T>(out T address, bool isSave, int? cID) 
where T: IAddress  
{ 
}
```

I feel there some design issues around, could you please post a code which calling `CreateAddress()` method for both `Address` and `Address_accessor` cases? Perhaps you are looking for a some kind of abstract factory?

Comment: Better yet, forget the generic entirely and just use IAddress instead of T.

Comment: This assumes a relevant link between the two types in a form only apparent for one of them (`Address`), if `IAddress` is being used for this purpose alone then this is a bad habit.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you need that code but you can convert result objects to T until return it:

```
object result = typeof(T) == typeof(Address_Accessor)
  ? (object) new Address_Accessor(dt, eID , sID)
  : (object) new Address(dt, eID, sID);

address = (T)result;
```

Comment: The assignment worked but error on the second one: 
address = (T)new Address(dt, eID, sID);

I think I can just use: 
address = (T)new Address_Accessor(dt, eID , sID);

without the if statement.

Comment: The other version is here, but you should think about changes in type hierarchy to solve this bug. My code is a round a way.

Comment: Different error: Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'Address_Accessor' and 'Address' -- I'm going to try a different approach for this code. Thanks.